# Google load balancer force https

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I not sure if this is possible (it wasn't last year according to the internet), but i'm hoping its available now.

Is there any way of using google load balancer to force https connection only, ie. get the load balancer to redirect http requests?

I can do it at the backend server, but i would rather have this handled by the load balancer.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Answer (score 1):

I think not. As far as I know, forcing HTTPS is not a managed feature of Google Cloud Load Balancer. It will not redirect HTTP to HTTPS for you. You can either drop the support of HTTP, or do the redirection in the backend. But it's would be a nice feature if they have.

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

Comment: Thanks... thats what i thought, but wasn't sure if i had missed something. It would be a nice feature if they add it.